# Returning a parsed XML node from a function in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm very new to rust - and am trying to write a function that reads a XML file, and returns a specific node of the file I am interested in.

This is what I tried:

```rust
use roxmltree;

pub fn load_from_str(text: &str) -> Result<roxmltree::Node, roxmltree::Error> {
    let doc = roxmltree::Document::parse(text)?;
    let tag = doc
        .descendants()
        .find(|x| x.tag_name().name() == "BODY")
        .expect("Unable to parser XML file");
    dbg!(tag);
    Ok(tag)
}
```

The error I get is:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `doc`
  --> src/main.rs:12:5
   |
7  |       let tag = doc
   |  ____________________-
8  | |         .descendants()
   | |______________________- `doc` is borrowed here
...
12 |       Ok(tag)
   |       ^^^^^^^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

I understand that `tag` is created from `doc`.

But I cannot figure out what I can do to be able to return `tag`

As a workaround, I believe I can return `doc` and then create `tag` outside this function ... but that kinda messes up the modular structure I am trying to maintain

Comment: There's not really a good way to do this within Rust's ownership rules, and it doesn't look like this is a supported use case of the library you're using. Is it required that this function return an actual XML node, or would transforming it into a proper Rust data structure using e.g. serde be more useful?

Comment: @cdhowie - I guess it is not exactly required. I was trying to create some abstract functions like `load_from_str()`, `load_from_file()`, `load_from_http()` which I could use. This is how I would have written it in python ... But I am open to understand the recommended way to do this in rust.  Could you elaborate on the serde approach ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the [source code](https://docs.rs/roxmltree/0.18.0/src/roxmltree/lib.rs.html#799) of `Node`:

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
pub struct Node<'a, 'input: 'a> {
    /// Node's ID.
    id: NodeId,

    /// The tree containing the node.
    doc: &'a Document<'input>,

    /// Node's data.
    d: &'a NodeData<'input>,
}
```

As can be seen, `Node` has a reference to `Document`, so you can't use it independently.

One option is to parse the document from the outside and pass it as a parameter (in which case you might need to specify lifetimes). Another option is to simply not return `Node` but some other data structure instead.

As a comparison, in [serde_json](https://crates.io/crates/serde_json) you could freely use the [Value](https://docs.rs/serde_json/latest/serde_json/value/enum.Value.html) enum ([src](https://docs.rs/serde_json/latest/src/serde_json/value/mod.rs.html#115)) independently. So it really is up to the crate authors to decide how to design their API.

Comment: I did try passing the `doc` from outside - and you are right. I got errors about lifetime, which led me down another rabbit hole ... And honestly I haven't yet understood lifetimes properly yet.So, am I understanding correctly that roxmltree library is not designed in a way that I can do this ... ever ?

Comment: @AbdealiLoKo Not the way your code currently works. A `Node` depends on an extant `Document`.  If you show the code where you tried passing in `doc`, we could help you figure out how to fix it.